# Working with TortoiseGit Locally

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I want to work with TortoiseGit locally without connecting to the server. I know how to work with remote server. I tried to create local repository by using TortoiseGit and created the projects into it.
I have followed the below steps:

- Created a new folder and create local repository in the folder. then .git folder got created.
- Created a project in the new folder.
- I do right click on the project and went to `TortoiseGit->Add->Commit`.

But here it was asking for setting the username and password. Then I went to `TortoiseGit->Settings->select` the Local radio button and pressed apply and ok. But the settings were not saved.

How would one set the TortoiseGit in a local environment.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an outdates TGit installation.

In mine (1.8.8.0), I've not set any credentials entered and TGit never asks:

[image: first screenshot]

[image: second screenshot]

Please note that I have set the credential helper to **none**.

Answer (score 0):

It has worked for me with TGit 1.8.9. Intially i thought i don't have to set user name and password for local repository but it works by adding username and email for local environment in settings.